# Get last 5 characters in a string

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the last 5 digits/characters from a string. For example, from `"I will be going to school in 2011!"`, I would like to get `"2011!"`.

Any ideas? I know Visual Basic has `Right(string, 5)`; this didn't work for me and gave me an error.

Comment: What was the error? Maybe post a code fragment too...

Comment: You're looking for the [`Substring` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=VS.71).aspx).

Comment: I think Right() function is not used in visual studio 2008 anymore.

Comment: In .NET 4.0 (With Visual Studio 2012) `Right(myString, 5)` does work and I'm using it successfully.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
str.Substring(str.Length - 5)
```

Comment: just make sure the `str.Length - 5` above doesn't result in a negative value.

Answer (score 29):

Error check:

```
result = str.Substring(Math.Max(0, str.Length - 5))
```

Answer (score 6):

Checks for errors:

```
Dim result As String = str
If str.Length > 5 Then
    result = str.Substring(str.Length - 5)
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Old thread, but just only to say: to use the classic `Left()`, `Right()`, `Mid()` right now you don't need to write the full path (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings`). You can use fast and easily like this:

```
Strings.Right(yourString, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

in VB 2008 (VB 9.0) and later, prefix Right() as Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(string, number of characters)

Dim str as String = "Hello World"

Msgbox(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(str,5))

'World"

Same goes for Left() too.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer of this post will cause an error in the case when the string length is less than 5. So I have a better solution. We can use this one line of code :

```
If(str.Length <= 5, str, str.Substring(str.Length - 5))
```

You can test it with a variable-length string.

```
    Dim str, result As String
    str = "11!"
    result = If(str.Length <= 5, str, str.Substring(str.Length - 5))
    MessageBox.Show(result)
    str = "I will be going to school in 2011!"
    result = If(str.Length <= 5, str, str.Substring(str.Length - 5))
    MessageBox.Show(result)
```

Another simple but efficient solution I found :

> str.Substring(str.Length - Math.Min(5, str.Length))

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.right("I will be going to school in 2011!", 5)
MsgBox("the value is:" & a)
```