# Is the VB string function RIGHT$ still part of current VB.NET or is it left over from old vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I just found the below line of code in a project I am working on. I have never seen functions with the $

I found online that it is a vb string function. The page said the "Right$" is more efficient than simply writing "Right"

So is this still current with the most up to date vb language features or is it deprecated?

```
Right$(sNumToBeFormatted, 8)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing that page with us?

Comment: I just tried it, and the compiler recognizes both, however, I would try opt for a more "pure .NET" way of doing it using the methods in the string class. In classic VB, using the dollar sign was more efficient, because it cast the result to string, rather than Variant, if my memory serves correctly. Since Variants don't exist in VB.NET, there is no reason to use it.

Comment: This question has some alternatives to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813505/get-last-5-characters-in-a-string

Comment: IMHO, `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right` is as likely to stay in VB.NET as, say, `If...Then...`. There is no exact equivalent of the former in the .NET framework.

Comment: Everything in `Microsoft.VisualBasic` is valid, current and supported. This is not necessarily true for `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility`, please do not confuse the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found online that it is a vb string function. The page said the "Right$" is more efficient than simply writing "Right"

VB6 had (and VBA still has) two versions of many string functions.
One version accepted and returned `String`s, another one accepted and returned `Variant`s. The string versions had `$` in their name to make them stand out.

One cannot say that using `Right$` is always better than using `Right`. It depends on the type of your source and result data.
If you receive data as `Variant`s and send it out as `Variant`s, like e.g. Excel does, using `Right` will result in fewer conversions between `String` and `Variant`.
If your data is originally a `String`, using `Right$` is better.

> So is this still current with the most up to date vb language features or is it deprecated?

VB.NET only includes the typed versions, but it does not show the `$` anymore.

So `Right$` is the up to date version, but it was renamed to simply `Right`. There is no choice anymore.

There is still choice in VBA, where both versions are valid and supported.

Answer (score 1):

`$` sign means that returned value of `Right` will be string

You can also do this

```
Dim someString$
```

which is equivalent to

```
Dim someString as String
```

For more go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx)

As to this question

> So is this still current with the most up to date vb language features
>   or is it deprecated?

There is nothing stopping you from using it as it is supported, but because it is not popular at all it shouldn't be so next person reading code wont be going over it like you are at the moment.

This syntax was already optional in vb6.